# text size limit not resizing properly at the create content form

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share

shareconfigcustom.xml
text box accepts unlimited characters with these parameters not resizing properly at the create form alfresco but working in edit-form(accepts defined number of characters)
Also is there any maximum limit for the number of characters ?

```
<config evaluator="node-type" condition="acme:document">
          <forms>
            <form>
              <field-visibility>
                 <show id="acme:anycustomproperty"/>
               </field-visibility>
               <appearance>
               <field id="acme:anycustomproperty" label-id="xqw">
                   <control template='/org/alfresco/components/form/controls/textfield.ftl' />
               <control-param name='maxlength'>5000</control-param>
           <control template='/org/alfresco/components/form/controls/textarea.ftl' />
               <control-param name='rows'>10</control-param> 
               <control-param name='columns'>10</control-param>
               </field>
               </appearance>
            </form>
          </forms>
        </config>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

textatrea.ftl only provides, rows & columns property. Please ensure that, you've used textarea.ftl, but your post says, that you've used, textfield.ftl.

**textarea.ftl**

```
<#if field.control.params.rows??><#assign rows=field.control.params.rows><#else><#assign rows=3></#if>
<#if field.control.params.columns??><#assign columns=field.control.params.columns><#else><#assign columns=60></#if>
```

Comment: thanks Murali,please see the edited code,rows and columns are fine but not  working well with no of characters which can be filled(like 5000 above)

Answer (score 0):

This configuration worked for me for edit and creation page as well

```
<control template="/org/alfresco/components/form/controls/textarea.ftl">
                     <control-param name="rows">4</control-param>
                     <control-param name="columns">4</control-param>
                     <control-param name="maxLength">5000</control-param>
                      </control>
```